# wordpress the_excerpt not working

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I can not seem to ger the_excerpt function to work.

Here is the code I am using

Am I not calling the loop right?
I am not using any filters in my functions.php for the_excerpt.

Any any would be great.

```
$col = 0;
$col_count = 3;
$cols = array();
// $my_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=projects&posts_per_page=3');
// while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'offset'=> 0, 'category_name' => 'projects' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); 
  if($col >= $col_count) $col = 0;
  ob_start();
  ?>
  <div class="post" id="post-'<?php the_ID(); ?>'">
    <span class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <div class="descr"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/lib/img/clock.png"> <?php the_time('F, jS'); ?>, <span class="author"><?php the_time('Y'); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></span></div>
    <div class="entry">
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $cols[$col++] .= $output;
 endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<div class="columns">
<?php
foreach($cols as $key => $col)
  echo '<div class="column column' . $key . '">' . $col . '</div>';
?>
</div>
```

Comment: define "not working". Nothing shows up?

Comment: are the other template tags outputting? Are you getting permalink, title, etc? A silly question-- is there text in either the post text editor or in the excerpt field?

Answer (score 1):

For the loop I always stick to:

```
query_posts('cat=6&showposts=10');

while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    // do stuff
    the_excerpt();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For calling post you can use this code

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => 3 );


$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Replace the Cat ID and number of post you want to display.

And for limiting the post character use this code

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php substr($post->post_content, 0, XY); ?> ...</a>
```

Change the number of character (XY) you want to dispaly...